# Reusable GridView Method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, methods, reusability

I have a page with multiple gridviews on it. All the gridviews have gridview methods that only vary by the gridview name. Is there a way to have a reusable method and run the code on the calling gridview?

For example, in both gridview1 and gridview2's RowCancelingEdit method both gridviews would have a line of:

```
[respectivegridview].EditIndex = -1;
```

The 'this' keyword is pulling the page class and not a gridview so I am not sure if/how to capture which gridview fired the method if I put something like:

```
OnRowCancelingEdit="gridviews_RowCancelingEdit"
```

in both gridview1 and gridview2's attributes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the method is an event handler or if you send the `sender` object to the method then the gridview can be pulled out by casting the sender to a `DataGridView` object.

```
private void datagridview_edit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((DataGridView)sender).EditIndex = -1;
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for! sender! I always forget about the scaffolded arguments passed. Thank you @Adam Kingsley